# Records navigation actions disabled in DomainComponent nested ListView when nested list constructed with FromSqlRaw

Tags: entity-framework-core, xaf

In my [demo project](https://github.com/kgreed/Things03) I set up data for a listview via EntityFrameworkCore FromRawSql

```
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC;
using DevExpress.Persistent.Base;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using Things03.Module.Functions;

namespace Things03.Module.BusinessObjects
{
    [NavigationItem("OldWayUseRibbonInstead")]
    [DomainComponent]
    public class ThingFilterHolder
    {
        public ThingFilterHolder()
        {
            ThingFilter = new ThingFilter();
            ApplyFilter();

        }
        [Browsable(false)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ThingFilter ThingFilter { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Thing> Things { get; set; }

        public void ApplyFilter()
        {
            var search = StringFunctions.SafeString(ThingFilter.Search);
            var sql = $"select Id, Name from Things where Name like '%{search}%'";
            var db = DataFunctions.MakeDbContext();
            Things = db.Things.FromSqlRaw(sql).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

I find the technique is very powerful.

However the Navigation actions are disabled and Refresh does not work.

I expect that this is because there is no underlying ObjectSpace that "knows" the listview collection.

[image: disabled navigation buttons]

The Next and Previous do enable if I add a record, but only for the added record.

If I enable diagnostics I see the following about the RecordsNavigationController

```
<Controller Name="RecordsNavigationController" FullName="DevExpress.ExpressApp.SystemModule.RecordsNavigationController" Active="True">
  <ActiveList>
    <Item Key="View is assigned" Value="True" />
    <Item Key="View type is ObjectView" Value="True" />
    <Item Key="PropertyEditor has ObjectSpace" Value="True" />
  </ActiveList>
  <Actions>
    <Action ID="PreviousObject" Caption="Previous Record" TypeName="SimpleAction" Category="RecordsNavigation" Active="True" Enabled="False" AdditionalInfo="">
      <ActiveList>
        <Item Key="Controller active" Value="True" />
        <Item Key="ByContext_RequireSingleObject" Value="True" />
        <Item Key="ListView or root DetailView" Value="True" />
        <Item Key="Editor doesn't support focused row selection." Value="True" />
      </ActiveList>
      <EnabledList>
        <Item Key="ByContext_RequireSingleObject" Value="True" />
        <Item Key="Can move to previous" Value="False" />
      </EnabledList>
    </Action>
    <Action ID="NextObject" Caption="Next Record" TypeName="SimpleAction" Category="RecordsNavigation" Active="True" Enabled="False" AdditionalInfo="">
      <ActiveList>
        <Item Key="Controller active" Value="True" />
        <Item Key="ByContext_RequireSingleObject" Value="True" />
        <Item Key="ListView or root DetailView" Value="True" />
        <Item Key="Editor doesn't support focused row selection." Value="True" />
      </ActiveList>
      <EnabledList>
        <Item Key="ByContext_RequireSingleObject" Value="True" />
        <Item Key="Can move to next" Value="False" />
      </EnabledList>
    </Action>
  </Actions>
</Controller>
```

The detail view is opened by an action on the toolbar.

```
using DevExpress.ExpressApp;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.Actions;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win;
using System.Linq;
using Things03.Module.BusinessObjects;

namespace Things03.Module.Win.Controllers
{
    public class ThingFilterController : ViewController
    {
        SimpleAction actThingScreen;
        public ThingFilterController() : base()
        {
            TargetViewNesting = Nesting.Root;
            actThingScreen = new SimpleAction(this, "Things", "View");
            actThingScreen.Execute += actThingScreen_Execute;
        }
        private void actThingScreen_Execute(object sender, SimpleActionExecuteEventArgs e)
        {
            var holder = new ThingFilterHolder();
            var holderType = holder.GetType();
            var viewId = Application.FindDetailViewId(holderType);
            if (SwitchToViewIfOpen(Application, viewId)) return;

            var os = Application.CreateObjectSpace(typeof(Thing));  // any valid type would have done
            var detailView = Application.CreateDetailView(os, holder);
            e.ShowViewParameters.CreatedView = detailView;
            e.ShowViewParameters.TargetWindow = TargetWindow.NewWindow;
            e.ShowViewParameters.NewWindowTarget = NewWindowTarget.MdiChild;
        }

        private bool SwitchToViewIfOpen(XafApplication application, string viewId)
        {
            if (!(application.ShowViewStrategy is WinShowViewStrategyBase strategy)) return false;
            foreach (var win in strategy.Windows.ToArray())
            {
                if (win.View == null) continue;
                if (!win.View.Id.Equals(viewId)) continue;
                win.Show();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/q510240/how-to-dynamically-assign-collection-for-a-listview-within-a-dashboard/

Comment: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t548092/how-to-dynamically-change-filter-list-in-a-nested-listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to populate the list via ObjectSpace

```
using DevExpress.ExpressApp;
using DevExpress.ExpressApp.DC;
using DevExpress.Persistent.Base;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using Things03.Module.Functions;

namespace Things03.Module.BusinessObjects
{
    [NavigationItem("OldWayUseRibbonInstead")]
    [DomainComponent]
    public class ThingFilterHolder 
    {
        public ThingFilterHolder()
        {
            ThingFilter = new ThingFilter();
            ApplyFilter();

        }
        [Browsable(false)]
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ThingFilter ThingFilter { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Thing> Things { get; set; }

        [Browsable(false)] public IObjectSpace ObjectSpace { get; set; }

        public void ApplyFilter()
        {
            var search = StringFunctions.SafeString(ThingFilter.Search);
            var sql = $"select Id, Name from Things where Name like '%{search}%'";
            var db = DataFunctions.MakeDbContext();
            var things1 = db.Things.FromSqlRaw(sql).ToList();
            Things = new List<Thing>();
            if (ObjectSpace == null) return;
            foreach (Thing t in things1)
            {
                Thing t2 = ObjectSpace.GetObject<Thing>(t);
                Things.Add(t2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to achieve this by adding an ObjectSpace property to the ThingFilterHolder and having the Action set the property.

I also had to override the refresh controller.

```
  public class MyRefreshController : RefreshController
    {
        public MyRefreshController() : base()
        {

        }

        protected override void Refresh()
        {

            var holder = View.CurrentObject as ThingFilterHolder;
            holder.ApplyFilter();
            View.Refresh();
            base.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

and the Delete

```
public class MyDeleteController : DeleteObjectsViewController
{
    public MyDeleteController() : base()
    {
        
    }

    protected override void Delete(SimpleActionExecuteEventArgs args)
    {
        base.Delete(args);
        View.ObjectSpace.CommitChanges();
    }

}
```